# Add a "table" feature to format tables in questions and answers

Tags: feature-request

I think it would be a really nice thing to be able to create simple tables in questions and answers. You would do it like this:

```
[table title="My Table1" orient="vertical" col="column1,column2,column3,column4"]
[row num="1" data="item1,item2,item3,item4"]
[row num="2" data="item5,item6,item7,item8"]
[/table]
```

But rather than type that all by hand, the format buttons (bold, italic, etc.) would contain a drop-down menu, "Create a Table" and be similar to the one in Microsoft Word 2007+. A table editor could also pop up in the same type of box as "Flag this Question" is.

If the dimensions are too great to display on the page, the upper-left-most corner is displayed, and then the column at the right is titled "(...)" and same with the bottom row. Clicking those would either scroll one window-width down/right via jQuery, or just open a pop-up window with scrollbars.

Comment: This request was also made on StackOverflow Meta in [2009](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16356/why-cant-table-markup-elements-be-used) and more recently in [2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97127/table-in-answers-questions) - apparently it is not a priority at this time.

Comment: @danlefree - Thanks, didn't see those when searching this meta, though searching across sites would also be a nice feature.

Comment: Closing as off-topic: this meta site is for things that relate to Pro Webmasters, not the entire network. This table feature request is not something that's specific to this site: it would affect other sites as well, and they should be able to comment on it. (Not migrating this because it's a duplicate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note also the [Markdown Editing Help](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page links through to the [What HTML tags are allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/33051) meta.SO FAQ which states in the answer:

> We do not and will not allow table tags -- sorry. This is intentional and by design. If you need a quick and dirty "table", use  and ASCII layout.